# Defining Excel solver parameters in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'd like to know how to define excel solver parameters in the pyopenxl library. Execution of code is not necessary. I've been thus unable to find anything in the docs regarding solver parameters.

While I'll probably generate the initial values using some other optimizer, certain required parameters are likely to be added post xlsx generation. I'd thus like to maintain the solver parameters to allow solving at a later stage.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not supported by `openpyxl`. The only scriptable method for setting Excel Solver parameters that I'm aware of is through VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-the-solver-vba-functions

Comment: Would there be a python package/method to define solver parameters, or would VBA be the only option?

Comment: VBA is the only option as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Solver is not part of the OOXML specification and, therefore, not supported by openpyxl.